# Code in latex for document of non latin alphabet

Tags: greek, code, alphabet

I need to include a code in a document written in greek. I found the command to include the code as it is written, but the letters appear with the greek alphabet in the compiled version. Does anybody know how to fix that. Thank you in advance.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You could do it even with pdLlaTeX, even with XeLaTeX even ocmbining both ways and making a cross-compiler document like here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/463430/120578 ... (Change the fonts to something accessible from your OS... and remove the `.ancient` from 'greek.ancient')